# How to create FrameNode with Figma API and paste it to design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, figma

I am creating custom Figma plugin with JS, so, I receive data from the backend and want to convert it to a frame so that it appears in the design. But actually I can not find methods of Figma API to release this idea.

Here JSON which I receive from my API
[image]